# How to convert multiple tex files with separate style tex file into rst format for making HTML via Sphinx with them?

Tags: html, type-conversion, python-sphinx, tex, pandoc

I have multiple tex files, each answering for one of the chapters of some manual, and main tex file, containing style and collecting them into one. I need to make HTML from all of it. I know that it can be done this way: tex -> markup via Pandoc, markup -> rst with Pandoc too and then rst -> HTML via Sphinx. But I can't find information on details. 
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If your original source contains all of the information you want to show in HTML, (i.e. you aren't going to use any additional explanations, auto-extracted docstrings, etc), then consider just using one tool rather than going via sphinx. 
[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc) is a great tool, but you could also consider one of the options described on the [TeX docs site](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=LaTeX2HTML) such as `latex2html`.

Also note that you don't usually need to go through the stages individually with pandoc: it can convert LaTeX directly to HTML.  E.g.:

```
pandoc -s source.tex -o web.html
```

The [pandoc demos](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html) page provides a quick way in with many syntax examples if you do find that you need to convert through other formats.